# AJAX GET fetching HTML of the page, and not the data - Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, model-view-controller, get

I have to populate the checkboxes on a page from the database. I am using an AJAX get method for fetching the record ID and it's corresponding right in a hash,

CoffeeScript:

```
$ ->
$(document).ready ->
 $.get('/server_management/getpair/').success (data) ->
   alert(data.toString()) # Shows nothing
   console.log(data) # Shows the HTML of the entire page
```

Controller:

```
 def getpair

 pair = UserServer.getpair
 render :nothing => true

 end
```

Model:

```
 def self.getpair

 UserServer.find_each do |us|
    if us.user_id == @uid # @uid is getting its value in another UserServer method
       pair[us.server_id] = us.right
    end
 end
 gair = pair # Just for the sake of 'last-assignment-is-a-return-in-ruby' thingy

 end
```

Now the problem is that the AJAX get is showing "Status Code:304 Not Modified" and the console.log(data) shows the HTML of the page.

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: um... you're rendering nothing... that means you get nothing back from the action. try rendering something eg perhaps `render json: pair` perhaps?

Comment: I'll shift it to an answer so you can accept it :) sometimes it's the simple things...

Comment: Simple and remindful of the importance of reading the theory first...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

um... you're rendering nothing... that means you get nothing back from the action.

Try rendering something eg perhaps `render json: pair`